# Liferay Hook for liferay-multi-vm-clustered.xml

Tags: caching, liferay, ehcache

I am trying to override the default **liferay-multi-vm-clustered.xml** for application level caching using a **liferay hook**. Any instruction or links? Already spent much time googling but didn't find anything useful.
Thanks in advance.

PS: Already know i can override it via manual deployment and portal.properties.
PPS: Sorry for the format new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're referring to Liferay 6.x

I'm not aware of any hook that can override this file. Specifically because hooks are only deployed after Liferay has fully been set up and started, it'd be changing the setup after the fact.

You can introduce a new file and reference it in portal-ext.properties. If you want to package this in a plugin, I'm afraid it'll be an ext-plugin. Even though I don't like to suggest using ext, in this case it's a well maintainable ext, so it does not bring the same maintenance-danger as code-containing ext plugins.